# Awk: check if field value is in one of the given

Tags: awk

I need to print all lines in which field $2 is one of the follows (23, 17, 21, 1)

```
awk -F $'\t' 'BEGIN { arr = (23, 17, 21, 1) } {if ($2 in arr) {print $0}}' file.txt
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk '$2~/^(23|17|21|1)$/' file
```

This will test if field `#2` is one of 23,17,21 or 1

---

Just en example on how to do it with array:

```
awk 'BEGIN{split("23 17 21 1",tmp); for (i in tmp) arr[tmp[i]]} $2 in arr' file
```

Make a variable `data` with number to use
Split it with `split` into array `arr`
Loop trough all value in `arr` fore every line and print if `$2` is found in arr.

EDIT: Updated with Eds suggestions.

Comment: +1 but `data="23 17 21 1";split(data,arr," ")` can be simply `split("23 17 21 1",arr)` and IMHO the better full solution is `'BEGIN{split("23 17 21 1",tmp); for (i in tmp) arr[tmp[i]]} $2 in arr' file` since then you don't need to loop through an array once for every line.

Comment: @EdMorton  Thanks for the update.  I know it could be shorten some, more posted it as an example.  Will update the post.